# How to sort recent orders after a specific column in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, grid

I tried to use this event `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` or `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` in my function:

```
public function setRecentOrderGrid( Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    echo $collection->getSelect();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }
}
```

but I m getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSelect() on null
```

I want to sort my grid  (in my case Recent Order grid) after a specific column `DESC` How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection object is not called `collection` in this case, it's `order_grid_collection`. Please try this instead ... then `getSelect()` should work again:

```
$collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
```

For setting sorting you can use `getSelect()->order('your_column DESC')`.

Comment: I used the getOrderGridCollection, i got the collection, but when I want to set the order, it doesn't work . I tried to change it from `DESC` to `ASC`, but I got the same results.

Comment: IF I do an `echo $collection->getSelect()` the change is applied on the query, but not in the displaying results :)

Comment: @Chester Do you use `before` or `after` event? (tested it successfully with before event ... sorting is correct only grid shows sorting on purchase date)

Comment: I am using right now this event : `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after`

Comment: @Chester Use `before` event .... with `after` event the collection is already loaded and `getSelect()->something()` has no effect.

Comment: Yep you are right. One more thing. How can I make to apply this change only on the recent orders? from the customer view.  Right now it is applied on the sales order grid too

Comment: @Chester I guess you can check controller/action/path (i.e. `if (...->getRequest()->getController() == 'customer' && ...->getAction() == 'edit'`)

Comment: You're welcome :)